# Azure CosmosDB Query on Sub Elements

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have such documents

```
   [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "My Product 1",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2179,
          "code": "A",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 1200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 500,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "My Product 2",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2180,
          "code": "B",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 1300,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "My Product 3",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2181,
          "code": "C",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 2000,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 999,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want now to find all products where one of the variants has the Height >= 1200 and Weight >= 500

In this example this should be My Product 1 and My Product 3. My Product 2 doesn't match as the Weight Property is below the criteria.

How can I do this. Is there a way. The data structure can be changed but only if really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow your document and created 3 sample documents as below in my cosmos db :

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "My Product 1",
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 2179,
        "code": "A",
        "attributes": {
          "att_set_1": {
            "en": {
              "name": "Attribute Set 1",
              "data": [
                {
                  "id": 919,
                  "title": "Height",
                  "label": "height_mm",
                  "v": 2330,
                  "unit": "mm"
                },
                {
                  "id": 921,
                  "title": "Weight",
                  "label": "weight",
                  "v": 2931,
                  "unit": "kg"
                },
                {
                  "id": 923,
                  "title": "Other",
                  "label": "blah",
                  "v": 200,
                  "unit": "mm"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "My Product 2",
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 2180,
        "code": "B",
        "attributes": {
          "att_set_1": {
            "en": {
              "name": "Attribute Set 1",
              "data": [
                {
                  "id": 919,
                  "title": "Height",
                  "label": "height_mm",
                  "v": 100,
                  "unit": "mm"
                },
                {
                  "id": 921,
                  "title": "Weight",
                  "label": "weight",
                  "v": 200,
                  "unit": "kg"
                },
                {
                  "id": 923,
                  "title": "Other",
                  "label": "blah",
                  "v": 200,
                  "unit": "mm"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "My Product 3",
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 2181,
        "code": "C",
        "attributes": {
          "att_set_1": {
            "en": {
              "name": "Attribute Set 1",
              "data": [
                {
                  "id": 919,
                  "title": "Height",
                  "label": "height_mm",
                  "v": 2000,
                  "unit": "mm"
                },
                {
                  "id": 921,
                  "title": "Weight",
                  "label": "weight",
                  "v": 999,
                  "unit": "kg"
                },
                {
                  "id": 923,
                  "title": "Other",
                  "label": "blah",
                  "v": 200,
                  "unit": "mm"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I use the SQL ：

> SELECT all FROM all join a in all.variants join b in
>   a.attributes.att_set_1.en.data where (b.title = 'Height' and b.v >=
>   2000) or  (b.title = 'Weight' and b.v >= 1000)

Result data:

```
[
  {
    "all": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "My Product 1",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2179,
          "code": "A",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 2330,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 2931,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "all": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "My Product 1",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2179,
          "code": "A",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 2330,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 2931,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "all": {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "My Product 3",
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 2181,
          "code": "C",
          "attributes": {
            "att_set_1": {
              "en": {
                "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                "data": [
                  {
                    "id": 919,
                    "title": "Height",
                    "label": "height_mm",
                    "v": 2000,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 921,
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "label": "weight",
                    "v": 999,
                    "unit": "kg"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 923,
                    "title": "Other",
                    "label": "blah",
                    "v": 200,
                    "unit": "mm"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Please notice that the `value` column is a keyword and cannot be used in a document. So, in my documents I remove it with v.

---

***Update Answer:***

After a few attempts, it seems impossible to directly query the results you want from the the Cosmos DB via the SQL statement.

However , Cosmos DB provides us with Stored Procedure when we face complex queries. If you do not know much about stored procedure, you can read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming).

Please refer to the stored procedure I created as below :

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM c',
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var returnArray = [];

            if (!feed || !feed.length){
                getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            } else{
                for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
                    var foundHeight = false, foundWeight=false;
                    var dataArray = feed[i].variants[0].attributes.att_set_1.en.data;
                    for(var j=0;j<dataArray.length;j++){
                      var f = dataArray[j];
                      if((f.title=='Height'&&f.v>=2000){
                        foundHeight = true; 
                      } else if(f.title=='Weight'&&f.v>=1000)){ 
                        foundWeight = true; 
                      }  
                    }
                    if(foundHeight && foundWeight) 
                       returnArray.push(feed[i]);
                }
            }
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(returnArray));
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

***Output result :***

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "My Product 1",
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 2179,
                "code": "A",
                "attributes": {
                    "att_set_1": {
                        "en": {
                            "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "id": 919,
                                    "title": "Height",
                                    "label": "height_mm",
                                    "v": 2330,
                                    "unit": "mm"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 921,
                                    "title": "Weight",
                                    "label": "weight",
                                    "v": 2931,
                                    "unit": "kg"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 923,
                                    "title": "Other",
                                    "label": "blah",
                                    "v": 200,
                                    "unit": "mm"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "My Product 3",
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 2181,
                "code": "C",
                "attributes": {
                    "att_set_1": {
                        "en": {
                            "name": "Attribute Set 1",
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "id": 919,
                                    "title": "Height",
                                    "label": "height_mm",
                                    "v": 2000,
                                    "unit": "mm"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 921,
                                    "title": "Weight",
                                    "label": "weight",
                                    "v": 999,
                                    "unit": "kg"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 923,
                                    "title": "Other",
                                    "label": "blah",
                                    "v": 200,
                                    "unit": "mm"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This result should be what you want. You can create it on portal or in your code. Any concern ,please let me know.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the example. The query would result all products where height or weight match. But I need products where one of the variants match the weight and the height.

Comment: @elvir.dolic Sorry ,I'm not sure what is the meaning of  'one of the variants match the weight and the height' here. Would you please simplify an example to let me help you figure out the correct sql?

Comment: I have edited my initial question. I have used your document and adapated the values. I hope this explains now the case.

Comment: @elvir.dolic Please give some time to update my answer.

Comment: @elvir.dolic Hi, any progress now?

Comment: Your stored procedure is doing the same the query did. Modifying it to this is the expected result. Maybe you can update your question and I will mark it as resolved
`var foundHeight = false, foundWeight=false; 
for(var j=0;j<dataArray.length;j++){
        var f = dataArray[j];
     if((f.title=='Height'&&f.v>=2000){
        foundHeight = true;
     }
    else if(f.title=='Weight'&&f.v>=1000)){
                           foundWeight = true;
                       }
}
if(foundHeight && foundWeight) 
    returnArray.push(feed[i]);`

Comment: @elvir.dolic Sure.I already modified my stored procedure as your snippet of code.Please check again.